# Amazon API connection issue with wordpress website

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I am trying to connect my amazon api with my wordpress website using aawp plugin but getting this error again and again:

> TooManyRequests: The request was denied due to request throttling. Please verify the number of requests made per second to the Amazon Product Advertising API.

Can someone kindly let me know the solution of this?

Comment: It sounds like your website is calling the API a lot, and Amazon have restricted it so that you can only call it so many times per second. I would suggest investigating how many API calls are made, and try to reduce how many their are.

Comment: Tim Thank you for your help. Actually i'm new to this stuff and don't know how to restrict api's from calling frequently. What you suggest! do i have to add new pair of keys if the existing pair of keys are being used many times ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AAWP myself, but you could try the suggestions at https://getaawp.com/docs/article/amazon-api-requestthrottled-how-to-fix/ and see if any of them help.

Comment: Tim I have already checked it but got no solution out of it. Thank you so much for your help :)